# Group Concat method in jquery data table

Tags: php, datatables, server-side-rendering

I have added the jquery data table and making the ajax request. On server side, I am using the joins of tables. The data table loads perfectly but search filter is not working properly. While searching ajax call shows that column "screen" is not found which is true as it does not exist in database. How can I solve that problem ?

```
 $data = self::sql_exec( $db, $bindings,

            "select r.title,group_concat(distinct n.name) as screens, group_concat(na.action) as permissions "."
             FROM `$table` as r
             left JOIN permissions p on p.role_id = r.id
             left join `navigations` n on n.id = p.nav_id 
            left join `navigation_actions` na on na.id = p.action_id 
             $where
             group by r.id
             $order
             $limit
             "
        );
```

Comment: Can you pust the full SQL query, so where $where, $order and $limit are filled in?
What data format does your data_table request? What does `var_dump($data);` show?

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be having another select statement on top of this statement.

Example (in mysql):

```
SELECT * FROM (

       "select r.title,group_concat(distinct n.name) as screens, group_concat(na.action) as permissions "."
             FROM `$table` as r
             left JOIN permissions p on p.role_id = r.id
             left join `navigations` n on n.id = p.nav_id 
            left join `navigation_actions` na on na.id = p.action_id 
             $where
             group by r.id
             $order
             $limit
         "
) AS my_table WHERE screens = "your_query_data"
```